# Why don't new emails with specific prefix (found with gmail keyword search) show up in gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail

Recently, I noticed that two emails never reached my inbox in gmail after friends asked if I received them, which I didn't.  When I did a keyword search on the subject of the email within gmail search, the subject now shows `[send secure]` as a prefix.  How do I configure gmail so that these show up in my inbox?

Comment: is the message archived? is any label assigned to the message?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a Gmail incoming mail filter based on subject?

Comment: @Blindspots - this is what I thought at first, but I don't have any filters configured since this is my correspondence email address, not my notifications email address.

Answer (score 0):

This is gmail's Confidentiality Mode feature.  By default, there are scenarios where email doesn't fall into the inbox or get removed automatically from the inbox when they expire.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect.  I'm not aware of labeling like that for Gmail's Confidential Mode.  The subject tag appears more likely to be from Cisco’s Registered Envelope Service. Why either of these would cause these messages to skip the inbox should be substantiated with links to documentation to make this answer more usefull.